# How to make these member elements fit in 3 bytes?

Tags: c++

I have a struct whose length should not exceed 14 bytes, and as of now I have 3 bytes remaining (11 bytes are already occupied).
I need to add 3 members
size whose value ranges from 40 - 8188
id1 whose value ranges from 1 - 257
id2 whose value ranges from 1 - 254
So I have

```
uint16_t size:13;
uint16_t id1:9;
uint8_t id2:8;
```

On the other hand, this will lead me to excess by 6 bits. What are the other ways to make this 3 members fit in 3 bytes? Id1 and Id2 should always be together.

Comment: You can't fit 30 bits worth of information into 24 bits of space!  You will have to either make more space available, or restrict the ranges of those values some more.

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible.

Logically speaking, the number of possible values you have is:

- 8148 different `size`s
- 256 different `id1`s
- 253 different `id2`s

That makes 8148*256*253 = 527729664 different combinations of values. 2^24, which is all the possibilities you get for three bytes, is only 16777216. Even if you combine all three numbers together you can't do it.

You **can** fit into 29 bits as is. Or you can restrict the range of values further.

If there is additional information about covariance - for example, "when `id2` is one, `size` is always greater than 500" you can use that to compress things more.

Answer (score 1):

If the total size of the struct is 14 bytes then there are two possibilities:

- `alignof(type) == 2`
- `alignof(type) == 4` or `alignof(type) == 8`

This depends on the members declared in the previous 11 bytes. It can't be aligned to 1 byte since you already have a member which is 13 bits.

Now in the first case you can't find a solution to your problem. Not only because `13+9+8 > 3*8` so there is no room (and there is no workaround for this, please see [first theorem of Shannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem)). But also for the fact that if the struct is aligned on 2 bytes boundary you can't have a bitfield which spans across a boundary (which is the case for `id1`, since 3 bits would reside in a 2 bytes group and the remaining in the others).

If the alignment is 4/8 bytes there are no problems, since 2 bytes are already there for padding (so effective size of struct is 16 bytes) and you have plenty to spare.

Comment: You're mistakenly assuming that all platforms must have alignment. There is no rule in C++ from which you can deduce that a 13 bits bitfield **must** cause 2 byte alignment. x86 is perhaps the best known example of an architecture that technically doesn't need alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to do range switch case statement?